# I submit a non-latin string value and it returns like %23%24%%%

Tags: characters

I am sorry I am anaware of the exact terms. 
I submit in non-latin a string and in the next page the value "%23%24..." returns.
How can I retrieve the correct value?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop wordpress from "correcting" my code?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66038/stop-wordpress-from-correcting-my-code)

Comment: Please note the `convert_chars` note in the previous answer link.

Comment: Sorry maybe my explanation is inadequate.
I mean "I submit a non-latin string in a form string variable. The receiving page makes a GET on the value and echoes it as %23%24 etc."
How can I fix this and echo the original string value?

Comment: This would then need to be asked at Stack Overflow as it's a strictly PHP question or search urldecode() on The Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urldecode() solves this problem, as suggested by @BrianFegter